# Why does Unbreakable have closing title cards?

Tags: film-techniques, unbreakable

> Just before the final credits, a **message appears that says** that David
>   contacted the authorities and Elijah is now in a mental institution.

Only movies based on real incidents/stories have closing title cards,
but I saw *Unbreakable* which is complete fiction has closing title cards.
Why so?

Comment: Well, definitely not "only" movies based on real events, there's always stuff like *Animal House*... That said, I agree that it's a strange choice. It felt like they didn't know how to end it, or hated the real ending and scrapped it, or just ran out of money. ;) (There is a clue [on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217869/alternateversions), though: *"Early previews of the movie didn't have the superimposed text ending, leaving a more open ending."* So it might have been added later after test screenings to tie it all in a neat bow for a disappointed audience.)

Comment: Where is that quoted text in your first paragraph from? If you got that from an external source, please reference that source (preferably with a link) for proper attribution.

Comment: It is certainly not a rule that only true stories use this technique.

Comment: I thought that was a weak ending myself. I've always thought they should have had a still shot of David, inside, sitting, staring into space, looking deep and thoughtful. Flashcut to police busting into Elijah's house. Back to David, still looking deep. Flashcut of Elijah trying to fight his arrest. Back to David. Cut to Elijah behind bars, angry but defeated, knowing his life of crime is over. Back to David, who gets up slowly, whips his "Security" cape around his shoulders, and walks out the front door ... to fight more crime. Cue heroic music and credits!

Comment: plenty of counterexamples at http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhereAreTheyNowEpilogue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Fast Times At Ridgemont High* (1982)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083929/) has closing title cards, I can't remember them all but Spiccoli supposedly saved a woman from drowning and spent the reward money hiring Van Halen to play his birthday party.  There are a number of other movies I know I've seen but can't recall off the top of my head, but this proves that title cards are not only strictly for stories based on real incidents.

Certainly, title cards are most often used as an epilogue in stories based on actual events, so it's possible M. Night Shyamalan wanted to create an air of truth to the story to make it creepier/more disturbing.

Comment: Spiccoli definitely _did_ save Brooke Shields from drowning :P